# Overriding Devise Passwords Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, devise, controller

I want to disable the

```
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end
```

so it won't redirect at all after sending the reset password

So, I created a new file under app/controllers/users/ called passwords_controller.rb

which looks like this

```
class User::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      flash[:notice] = "sent password"
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end

  def new
    super
  end

  def update
    super       
  end

  def edit
    super   
  end
end
```

and changed in my routes to

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'users/invitations', :passwords => 'users/passwords' }
```

I also have the devise_invite gem..

When I click on a link for forgotten password I get this error

```
Started GET "/users/password/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-16 10:21:07 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Users::PasswordsController):
```

my `rake routes` are

```
              user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                  users/passwords#create
          new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)              users/passwords#new
         edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)             users/passwords#edit
                            PUT    /users/password(.:format)                  users/passwords#update
```

the link in the view is

```
<%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(User) , :class => "control-group", :style => "position: absolute; bottom: 0", :id=>"forgotpass" %>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe that because typos

Comment: I don't understand where

Comment: In your view, change `new_password_path(User)` to `new_user_password_path`

Comment: maybe need to change `User::PasswordsController` to `Users::PasswordsController`

Answer (score 16):

The password controller is extended from devise password controller. So, extend the password controller with devise password controler.

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  ......................

end
```

Change the routes for password controller with devise

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" }
```

and the routes will be like this :-

```
user_password       POST   /password(.:format)       Passwords#create

new_user_password   GET    /password/new(.:format)   Passwords#new

edit_user_password  GET    /password/edit(.:format)  Passwords#edit
                    PUT    /password(.:format)       Passwords#update
```

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" }` with a lowercase "p"?

Comment: Yes, `{ :passwords => "Passwords" }` didn't work.
Use `{ :passwords => "passwords" }`

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to keep a namespace, try:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: 'users/passwords' }

# users/passwords_controller.rb
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  ...
end
```